# How to show $[f^{-1}][f]\cong e_x?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

$\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is  a group with respect to the product $[f][g]=[f.g]$

satisfy three properties

$1. $Associative

$2.$ Identity :$[c]$ where $c$ is the constant loop i,e $c(s)=x_0$ for any $s$

$3.$Inverse:The inverse  of $[f]$ will $[\bar f]$ , where  $\bar f(s)= f(1-s)$

**My question** : How to show the inverse  properties in $\pi_1(X,x_0)?$

**My attempt** :   our motive  $[f][f^{-1}] \cong e_x $ and $[f^{-1}][f]\cong e_x$

First case : to show $[f][f^{-1}] \cong e_x $

Proof : $[f]\cdot [f^{-1}](t)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2t)& 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f(2(1-t) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Now we can construct a homotophy between  $[f][f^{-1}]$ and $e_x$ i,e given by

$H : I \times I  \to X$ is given by

$H(t,s)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2t(1-s)& 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f\left((2-2t)(1-s))\right) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

$H(t,0)= [f][f^{-1}](t)$  and since $f$ is a loop so  $H(t,1)= f(0) =e_x(t) $

where  $e_x$ denote the constant path $ e_x:[0,1] \to X$  defined by  $e_x(t)=x$ for all $t\in [0,1]$

This implies that  $H$ is homotopy relative $\{0,1\}$

Therefore $[f][f^{-1}] \cong e_x $

**My doubts** : my doubt is  in converse direction that

How to show  $[f^{-1}][f]\cong e_x?$

Comment: What kind of problems do you have when proving $f^{-1}*f\simeq e_x$? Defining the path or something else?

Comment: @Kevin.S  my problem is  how to define $ H(t,s)?$

Comment: You can use the same technique. Is there any issue?

Comment: can u give some hints ?@Kevin.S

Comment: $$H(s,t)=\begin{cases} x &\text{ if } 0\leq s\leq \frac{t}{2},\\ f(1+t-2s) &\text{ if } \frac t 2\leq s\leq \frac 12,\\ f(t+2s-1)&\text{ if } \frac12 \leq s\leq 1-\frac t2,\\ x&\text{ if } 1-\frac t2 \leq s\leq 1. \end{cases}$$

Comment: $H(-,0)=f^{-1}*f$ and $H(-,1)=e_x$.

Comment: thanks u @User873110 you can write in answer box  if u have time

Comment: @jasmine You can also write an answer to your [own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) which would help you to get a better understanding. By the way, your proof of $[f] \cdot [f^{-1}] = e_x$ is correct. Since it works for any $f$, it also works for $g = f^{-1}$ which gives you the desired result.

Comment: @PaulFrost i have done it

Comment: @jasmine And you can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof : $[f^{-1}]\cdot [f](t)= \begin{cases} 
      f^{-1}(2t)& 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f(2t-1) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

**Note**: $f^{-1}(2t)= f(1-2t) $

$[f^{-1}]\cdot [f](t)= \begin{cases} 
      f(1-2t)& 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f(2t-1) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Now we can construct a homotophy between  $[f^{-1}][f]$ and $e_x$ i,e given by

$H : I \times I  \to X$ is given by

$H(t,s)= \begin{cases} 
      f((1-2st)& 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f\left((2t-1)s+(1-s))\right) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

since $f$ is a loop so  $H(t,0)= f(1) =e_x(t) $

so,$H(t,0)= f(1)=e_x(t)$  and

$H(t,1)=[f^{-1}][f]$

where  $e_x$ denote the constant path $ e_x:[0,1] \to X$  defined by  $e_x(t)=x$ for all $t\in [0,1]$

This implies that  $H$ is homotopy relative $\{0,1\}$

Therefore $[f^{-1}][f] \cong e_x $